# How to pair programmatically BLE device(nRF 52840) with iOS iPhone using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

When I try to connect my `device(iOS Application)` to my `peripheral(BLE Device)`, I want to send this passkey programmatically during the connection. I'm using `BleManager` but I can't find a way to send it programmatically. Please provide your valuable inputs and suggestion.

[image]

Comment: You are working on an iOS app, right? Because the screenshot if from Android...

Comment: Does `BleManager` refer to this [library](https://github.com/iqvis/BLEManager-iOS)?

Comment: I am working on iOS but I need functionality in iOS which given in screenshot.